# How to upload both json data and file using django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm making use of django default restapi.

![This is the default api][1]

Before adding file I upload the other fields in json format in the content textbox. Now I have file to upload.
I've tested my code with postman, it works fine because it has provided file browse option.

In api I don't have file browse option, How to add file browse option to default api or is there any way to give file in json itself(this didn't work as I gave file path in json).

MODEL.PY

```py
class requests(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    md5 = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    sha1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    sha256 = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    taskType = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    filename = models.FileField(max_length=1000, null=True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id 

from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class RequestsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.requests
        fields = ('md5', 'sha1', 'sha256','filename', 'taskType')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhkuP.png

Comment: providing in the json data doesn't mean anything for the model, you can process the json data in the api view to download the file (process it) and save to a file field. Providing path as a sting also does not mean anything for the server, it is in your local filesystem. Such data can be provided in base64 or "multipart/form-data" form type instead of json. You can check [this](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/uploading-images-drf/) tutorial about file uploads in DRF

Comment: I've checked the tutorial. postman is used to test and I'm also able to upload via postman but when coming to api as I don't have any option to browse file I'm not able to post the api

Comment: not having the field to browse the file usually means it is missing in the Serializer class. I need to see your model and serializer to understand what is the problem

Comment: have added model and serializer in question

Comment: media type in your page should be multipart, not application/json. Can you change it and test again?

Comment: while posting I'm changing media type to multipart form data but where to upload file in api.

Comment: anyidea how to add file browser to api

Comment: Check your model in the django admin first to make sure it is working well. Second thing, the page should have all fields that are mentioned in the serializer, what is provided for the field "filename"?

Comment: you mean html template..??

Comment: I mean first of all, check your django admin page (`localhost:8000/admin/`) to see how your model works. Django provides a default admin interface for CRUD operations. Second thing is to check the DRF page where your endpoint is shown (you posted part of the page as an image). You need to check how this page shows the field "filename" there. Your serializer looks good and should have a file picker in that page.